# How to map a list of graphics objects to a collection of symbols? Using `(define-values)`?

Tags: racket

I'm trying to learn Racket by following the code samples from "Realm of Racket". Currently at Chapter 8, and I decided to refactor some repetitive code to help myself learn quicker. Specifically, I'm trying assign a list of the game graphics to a collection of symbols, but I keep running into errors.

This is the original `orc-world.rkt` source file. The code works fine.

```lisp
(require 2htdp/image)

;; compute constants for image frames 
(define ORC     (bitmap "graphics/orc.png"))
(define HYDRA   (bitmap "graphics/hydra.png"))
(define SLIME   (bitmap "graphics/slime.bmp"))
(define BRIGAND (bitmap "graphics/brigand.bmp"))

(define PIC-LIST (list ORC HYDRA SLIME BRIGAND))
(define w (apply max (map image-width PIC-LIST)))
(define h (apply max (map image-height PIC-LIST)))

(define PLAYER-IMAGE  (bitmap "graphics/player.bmp"))

(define FRAME (rectangle w h 'outline 'white))
(define TARGET (circle (- (/ w 2) 2) 'outline 'blue))

(define ORC-IMAGE     (overlay ORC FRAME))
(define HYDRA-IMAGE   (overlay HYDRA FRAME))
(define SLIME-IMAGE   (overlay SLIME FRAME))
(define BRIGAND-IMAGE (overlay BRIGAND FRAME))
```

Basically, it is reading a bunch of bitmap images from disk and assigning them to symbols. There's a lot of code duplication. I'm trying to change it so that code duplication is minimized, while learning more about how Racket's standard libraries work.

My version, ignoring the `(overlay)` code for now:

```lisp
(require 2htdp/image)

(define BASEPATH "/Applications/Racket v7.3/share/pkgs/realm/chapter8/graphics/")
(define FILENAMES '("orc.png" "hydra.png" "slime.bmp" "brigand.bmp" "player.bmp"))
(define PATHS (map (lambda (x)(string-append BASEPATH x)) FILENAMES))
(define PICTURES (map (lambda (x)(bitmap/file x)) PATHS))
(define PIC-LIST '(ORC HYDRA SLIME BRIGAND PLAYER-IMAGE))
```

I wish to **iterate through the list of PICTURES, and assign each picture to a symbol, which is in a list.** I could just do a `(define ORC (first PICTURES))` `(define HYDRA (second PICTURES))` etc but that isn't what is wanted. It seems like we could use `(map)` since both are lists of the same length, but I get the following errors.

```lisp
(map (lambda x y)(define x y) PIC-LIST PICTURES) ; error. define: not allowed in an expression context in: define

(map (lambda x y (define-values (x) (values y)) PIC-LIST PICTURES)) ; error. define-values: not allowed in an expression position in: (define-values (x) (values y))

(map (lambda (x y)(define x y))PIC-LIST PICTURES) ; error. begin (possibly implicit): no expression after a sequence of internal definitions in:
;  (begin (define x y))
;  (define x y)
```

Using `(define-values)` by itself does not work either.

```lisp
(define-values PIC-LIST (values PICTURES)) ; syntax error because PIC-LIST is a list
```

Was hoping someone would be kind enough to point me on the right path. It must be something super easy that I'm overlooking since this is a pretty common task.

Thank you for reading this far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`match-define`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fmatch..rkt%29._match-define%29%29) like this:

```
 (match-define (list ORC HYDRA SLIME BRIGAND PLAYER-IMAGE) IMAGES)
```

It'll work as long as the number of images is known in advance, you can't pass a list of variable names as argument (we're doing *pattern matching* here.)

Which is ok, I guess - because anyway you should know how you want to name your images, how many of them you have and in what order they appear before assigning a name to each one of them. If I had to refactor the original code, this is how it'd look:

```
#lang racket

(require 2htdp/image)

(define paths '("graphics/orc.png"
                "graphics/hydra.png"
                "graphics/slime.bmp"
                "graphics/brigand.bmp"
                "graphics/player.bmp"))

(match-define (list ORC HYDRA SLIME BRIGAND PLAYER-IMAGE)
  (map bitmap paths))
(define PIC-LIST (list ORC HYDRA SLIME BRIGAND))

(define w (apply max (map image-width PIC-LIST)))
(define h (apply max (map image-height PIC-LIST)))
(define FRAME (rectangle w h 'outline 'white))
(define TARGET (circle (- (/ w 2) 2) 'outline 'blue))

(match-define (list ORC-IMAGE HYDRA-IMAGE SLIME-IMAGE BRIGAND-IMAGE)
  (map (λ (img) (overlay img FRAME)) PIC-LIST))
```

Notice that there are three different lists of variables, and we define each one exactly once, so the code duplication is minimized.

Comment: Hello, thank you for responding. That's not it; I intentionally left out including `#lang racket` from my post to focus on the problem I'm experiencing.

Comment: I'm getting an error on the above code because obviously my filesystem looks different, but other than that I'm not getting the `define` error you mention. Are you sure that the 5 lines in your question are the ones that trigger a `define` error? As I see it, the result of your code is simply a list of `image`s named `PICTURES`, with no errors whatsoever.

Comment: I'll edit the original post to make things clearer.

Comment: @Greenhorn that's a different thing, now the question is clear. Please always make sure that the code you post in your questions actually reproduces the problem and produces the error messages you got.

Comment: OK got it. Thanks!